# Azure Mobile App - How can a ping takes 7 seconds?

Tags: performance, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to improve my azure mobile app performance.

However just calling the web app root url (azure static "This mobile app is up and running" page) with fiddler can take up to 7 sec.

I'm lost how it's even possible and what I can and should do to improve it.

My current plan is B1 and "Always On" is On.

UPDATE

The long time where a combination of two things:

- Long DNS Lookup
- Log warmup of the mobile app after a deployment

Both issues can be addressed differently. For the warmup, check @arianhall answer below (which I marked as correct). For DNS lookup it can be many things. In my case the problem was broader: my ipv6 dns server was bad and it wouldn't switch to ipv4 after some timeout.

ps: and it's not a ping I was doing but a webpage load as azurewebsites [don't accept ping](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fb37b756-3581-4692-90e1-82e47814da94/i-cant-ping-a-site-in-azure-websites?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irrespective of whether AlwaysOn is on or not, the first request after a deployment results in a "wake-up" cost.  To fix that, you need to warm up the site.  This blog post will describe how to do this: http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/

Comment: as per my update my problem was more a dns issue but generically your answer is what ppl will look for :-)